# networkd and wpa_supplicant with roaming

Tags: networking, 18.04, wpa-supplicant, systemd-networkd

I've just switched from 16.04 to 18.04 and I'm having issues when I do a wireless roam. My use case involves heavy roaming and I need to make roams as transparent as possible (ideally < 50ms).

I have a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file which is set up to use `FT-PSK` (802.11r) which was working well on 16.04 but now seems to be conflicting with networkd in some way after upgrading. Now on every roam the connection is dropped and a full reconnect/authenticate is done.

Firstly, this is the "error" I get:

```
Oct 09 10:07:07.092601 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Oct 09 10:07:07.153867 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be (SSID='<ssid>' freq=5540 MHz)
Oct 09 10:07:07.157115 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: disconnect from AP f2:cb:ac:8a:e8:1f for new auth to f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be
Oct 09 10:07:07.161137 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticate with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be
Oct 09 10:07:07.164717 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: send auth to f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be (try 1/3)
Oct 09 10:07:07.165019 p3-1337 systemd-networkd[517]: wlp2s0: Lost carrier
Oct 09 10:07:07.165029 p3-1337 systemd-networkd[517]: wlp2s0: DHCP lease lost
Oct 09 10:07:07.165457 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: Withdrawing address record for 10.101.65.100 on wlp2s0.
Oct 09 10:07:07.165481 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.101.65.100.
Oct 09 10:07:07.165500 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 09 10:07:07.191354 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: FT: Failed to set PTK to the driver
Oct 09 10:07:07.191375 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be (SSID='<ssid>' freq=5540 MHz)
Oct 09 10:07:07.193143 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: authenticated
Oct 09 10:07:07.193183 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: associate with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be (try 1/3)
Oct 09 10:07:07.197111 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: RX ReassocResp from f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 09 10:07:07.201117 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: associated
Oct 09 10:07:07.201715 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: Associated with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be
Oct 09 10:07:07.201741 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Oct 09 10:07:07.201753 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct 09 10:07:07.201833 p3-1337 systemd-networkd[517]: wlp2s0: Gained carrier
Oct 09 10:07:07.203939 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 09 10:07:07.205485 p3-1337 wpa_supplicant[724]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Oct 09 10:07:07.229116 p3-1337 kernel: wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 21 (24 - 3) dBm as advertised by f2:cb:ac:8a:e4:be
Oct 09 10:07:11.067584 p3-1337 systemd-networkd[517]: wlp2s0: DHCPv4 address 10.101.65.100/18 via 10.101.64.1
Oct 09 10:07:11.067663 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.101.65.100.
Oct 09 10:07:11.067960 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 09 10:07:11.067973 p3-1337 avahi-daemon[655]: Registering new address record for 10.101.65.100 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Oct 09 10:07:11.068265 p3-1337 systemd-networkd[517]: wlp2s0: Configured
```

I think this is showing networkd cleanup up the interface mid-roam and hence an entirely new connection needs to be established. Previously there was no DHCP request so I know this is a new change.

netplan config

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            addresses:
              - 1.2.3.4/24
              - 1.2.4.5/24
        wlp2s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

wpa_supplicant config

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0

country=us
filter_ssids=1

# We don't use p2p networks so we can disable this to speed up startup.
p2p_disabled=1

# Not used if 802.11r works but speeds up roam when it doesn't.
okc=1

network={
  ssid="dummy_ssid"
  psk="notarealpassword"

  # Increase scanning frequency when signal goes below -65dBm.
  bgscan="simple:10:-65:300"

  # Enable 802.11r to get fast roams
  key_mgmt=FT-PSK
  proto=RSN
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP
}
```

Any ideas what is going on? I realize this is a bit of a niche use case so should I just be reverting from using networkd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, there was a change in the kernel introduced in 4.20 which clears the ARP cache every time a wifi roam happens which in turn causes the large delay I was seeing. The other errors I mention are "normal".

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666620/send-delay-after-wifi-roam/685883